# Oman Air - Batteries in carry-on luggage

Tags: hand-luggage, batteries, drones

I bought a ticket for a flight from Munich to Sri Lanka via Muscat with Oman Air. I want to take a bunch of 1300mah LiPo batteries for my drone in my carry-on luggage. Does Oman Air have any special restrictions on batteries?

Comment: Usually, this kind of question is answered by looking at the airline's website. However, I was unable to find anything beyond a generic page listing [broad categories of prohibited items](http://www.omanair.com/sites/default/files/content/travel_info/pdf/DangerNotice.pdf) ("Explosives, flammable gas, flammable liquid, flammable solid, ..., corrosive, other dangerous goods" -- wow, helpful). Generally, high-capacity batteries are prohibited in checked baggage so you should probably take them in carry-on. Tweet or email the airline to ask them and let us know what they say.

Answer (score 2):

Oman Air's [restricted items](http://www.omanair.com/sites/default/files/content/travel_info/pdf/DangerNotice.pdf) include corrosives, which may not be in either checked or carry on baggage.

> [**Your Baggage**](http://www.omanair.com/en/travel-info/preparing-fly/things-note)
>
> For safety reasons dangerous articles such as Compressed gases, Corrosives, Etiologic agents, Explosives, Flammable liquids and solids, Radio-active materials, Oxidizing materials, Poisons and other articles such as mercury, magnetized material, Illegal Drugs and Narcotics, offensive and irritating material shall not be packed in Checked or Hand baggage. You may please check with Oman Air office if you need to clarify on any item that needs to be carried.
>
> [Click here to view restricted articles](http://www.omanair.com/en/travel-info/baggage-services#conditions_carriage)

It does not specifically list lithium polymer batteries, but it does not exclude them. Of note is that, since the Fall of 2016, [Oman Air has restricted](http://timesofoman.com/article/97139/Oman/Science-/Power-banks-not-allowed-in-check-in-baggage-say-airlines-officials-in-Oman) a similar item, power banks, limiting it to carry on baggage and to no more than two.

For those reasons, you may want to ask in advance:

Munich Contacts
Reservations / Ticketing: 0049 69 58300710
Res.Germany@omanair.com
Administration: 0049 69 58300790
admin.fra@omanair.com

Also worth knowing is that, upon arrival in Oman, all baggage, both carry on and checked, is x-rayed.

> [**Transferring passengers**](https://www.omanairports.co.om/Page.aspx?MID=25&PGID=15)
>
> You may be transferring in Oman, awaiting an onward flight to another destination. We would like to make your transfer as pleasant as possible.
>
> The Transfer Area is to the left of the immigration hall and is well sign posted. All transferring passengers should proceed to the First Floor and should collect boarding cards if these were not issued at the point of origin. Lifts are available to the first floor Transfer Area.
>
> All transferring passengers will be security screened, including x-rays of hand baggage.
>
> Pursuant to Regulation (E C) 154/2006, some items may not be carried in as Unchecked Baggage or may be limited to an authorised quantity and subject to separate screening procedures. For more details, [please consult us](https://www.omanairports.co.om/ContactUsNew.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

So, I recently took a flight to Manila from Paris  with my drone and batteries in my LiPo bag and card cases.  When I advised the ticket agent that I had the Mavic inside the bag I was about to check in, she was shocked.  Called her manager and advised me that it was not allowed through Muscat, Oman.  They made me take out my drone and hold it in the airport until I return.  BIG HEADACHE.

If my final destination is Manila, and only stopping over in Oman to change planes, why couldn't I have taken my mavic with me in my checked-luggage?

Now, I'm trying to get in contact with the Muscat airport security as well as OmanAir to clarify.